# Generate multiple messages

Tags: apache-camel

I've got a scenario where one message can generate multiple messages to be processed independently of the original.

I have tried the splitter EIP but it looks like it has a default aggregation strategy (which I can't seem to be able to turn off).

Can I achieve this route:

```
from("direct:in").to("bean:multipleMsgGenerator").to("direct:out")
```

where multipleMsgGenerator can send n number of independent messages to "direct:out" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The splitter by default returns the original message (camel_version >= 2.3). See http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html. That said you can do whatever you want to do with the individual splitted messages inside the spilt block.

If the body of the message is a List for instance you can do this:

```
from ("direct:in)
  .split(body())
    .to("direct:processIndividualMsg")
  .end()
  .to("direct:doSomethingWithTheOriginalMsg");
```

Comment: I understand now, I experimented around a bit and understand the splitter EIP much better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this question, we found a solution which suited us.
We received a message which needed to pass forward multiple messages.  This can be done using:
1. A custom processor which creates a List and sets this into the body of the exchange
2. A split().body() after the custom processor
3. The Camel Split logic takes the List and notices it's a list of items, so iterates through it to get the messages to pass forwards
(This is done in Camel by org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter -> SplitterIterable, 
which calls ObjectHelper.createIterator(value) )

Some example code:

The route:

```
from("direct:myRouteEntrypoint")
.to("myProducer")
.split().body()
.to("log:logProducedMessages");
```

The custom producer:

```
/**
 * MyProducer
 * 
 * Produces a List of String objects and sets that List into the body of
 * the message, to then be later "split"
 */
public class MyProducer implements Processor {
    public MyProducer() {
    }

    public void process(final Exchange inExchange) {

        List<String> ongoingMessages = new ArrayList<>();

        // some loop for each message
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            String body = "Output message from MyProducer, this is output message: " + i;
            body += ", original message body: " + inExchange.getIn().getBody();
            ongoingMessages.add(body);
        }

        inExchange.getIn().setBody(ongoingMessages);
    }
}
```

You can see each "ongoing message" can access the original message that initiated it.
If you run this code, and send one message into the route, you'll see 5 ongoing messages being created and sent to the "logProducedMessages" logger.